# How do you prepare a rabbit?

Tags: meat, barbecue, rabbit

A family member gave me a couple rabbits to cook and I'm not sure how to prepare them. I'd prefer something on the smoker or grill. Do I marinate, rub, brine? I'm just not sure how to prepare it.

Comment: How'd they get the rabbits? I've often wanted to cook some rabbit myself, but living in Chicago I can't exactly trap them easily.

Comment: What's a "smoker" A smoke room?

Comment: @hobodave Our grocery store here sells D'Artagnan brand rabbits. http://www.dartagnan.com/51337/Farm--Raised-Natural-Rabbit.html

Comment: I got the rabbit from my brother in law who went rabbit hunting.

Comment: I found a page with several links about grilling rabbit that you might find helpful: "http://www.slashfood.com/2008/06/13/extreme-grilling-rabbit/".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Easter, a friend and I cooked rabbits.

We marinated for 72 hours in buttermilk, dijon, rosemary, and sage (NO SALT). Then boned them out and spatchcocked them (sort of a butterfly, with skewers to hold the flat spread out shape), seasoned, and roasted at 350 until done. Moist, flavourful. Served with parsnip puree, rosemary potatoes roasted in duck fat, and sorry but I forget the other veg we used.

Answer (score 7):

I can't tell you what to do but I can tell you one thing not to do: don't chop up the bones, they're very brittle and if you do you'll end up with little shards of bone all over the place; especially bad if you make a rabbit stew; joint the bones instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be careful to make sure it doesn't dry out, as they generally aren't particularly fatty. If you joint it so that the pieces aren't too thick, or splay it out well, you should be able to grill it so you get a good taste on the outside and cook all the way through before it goes dry. Marinading can help, although I just like rabbit rubbed with salt and pepper.

I've not used a smoker before, but I suspect you'd have to leave the meat in their for too long to get a good smokiness, so that may not work.

I've made rabbit pie before, with sausage meat and rabbit mixed together, which worked rather well.

Answer (score 2):

Cook it using any chicken recipe.  Used to make fried chicken for my kids using rabbit.  Also jambalaya and stew.  We all loved it.

Answer (score 1):

If making rabbit stew, soaking the rabbit in salted water before disjointing it will make it easier to prepare. Also cooking it slowly, at a low to medium heat will keep the meat tender. If cooking from a whole rabbit, once the rabbit has been gutted the insides should be cleaned with vinegar and it should be thoroughly rinsed. Marinating it will also keep the meat tender. 
I'm not sure but I think smoking it would dry it out too much. Stewing works best ime, but if roasting it it needs a lot of basting and checking to make sure it's not drying out.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit is pretty lean, so you'll need a slow wet technique.

I've made a great Spanish rabbit stew, which is basically rabbit joints, tomato sauce and about 2 cups of dry cured olives.

I'll look up the recipe and edit tomorrow.